# Make footers non-overlapping with content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the following web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    min-width: 380px;
}

main {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

footer {
    padding: 10px 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: inherit;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;

}

  </style>
  <main>
  {{{content}}}
  </main>
  <footer>
   {{{footer}}}
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

A jsfiddle with some long text instead of the placeholders is available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aL1svpdh/).

When the content in `<main>` goes beyond the position of the footer, it starts overlapping with the content; and I'm unable to find a way to keep the footer at the bottom (when there is too little content) and not have it overlap with the content at the same time.

Is there a way I can keep the footer at the bottom when there's very little content, and also have it not overlap with the content in `<main>`?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `footer {position:fixed;}`

Answer (score 0):

Add to the footer the `position:fixed` and to the body a `padding-button:50px`

here are a working example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k92mfxgv/)